# Blender - Texto distorsionado al envolverlo al rededor de un cilindro

Tags: blender

Estoy intentando proyectar un texto sobre un cilindro (el cilindro es el bote, y el texto es como si fuese una etiqueta del producto). El problema es que al aplicar el modificador Shrinkwrap el texto se deforma en los lados, se comprime tanto a la derecha como a la izquierda.

También he intentado usar una lattice (caja de deformación) añadiendo el modificador lattice al text, y aplicando el modificador Shrinkwrap a la caja de deformación, pero el resultado es el mismo.

Alguien puede ayudarme?
Gracias, un saludo.

[image: The deformed text]

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/). El idioma oficial de este sitio es el español, por lo que puede traducir su pregunta o rehacerla en [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).
  
Welcome to [Stack Overflow in Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/). Official language in this site is spanish, so either translate your question, or redo it on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa gracias, no me había dado cuenta. Ya esta traducida.